# Global constants in Groovy

Tags: groovy, global-variables

It is often desired to declare constants at the top of a script that can be referenced anywhere else in the script.  In Groovy, it seems that if you declare a constant using final  then it isnot accessible in child scopes.  What is the solution for this very basic and common requirement?  The workaround I have right now is to create an unbound variable but this is not a constant and is not elegant.

Answer (score 112):

Groovy doesn't really have a global scope.  When you have a groovy script that doesn't declare a class, it implicitly gets stuck in a class with the name of the script.  So final variables at the top-level scope are really just fields of the implicit class.  For example:

```
// foo.groovy
final MYCONSTANT = "foobar"
println MYCONSTANT

class Helper {
    def hello() { println MYCONSTANT }  // won't work
}
new Helper().hello()
```

Is more or less equivalent to:

```
class foo {
    def run() {
        final MYCONSTANT = "foobar"
        println MYCONSTANT
        new Helper().hello()
    }
    static main(args) {
        new foo().run()
    }
}

class Helper {
    def hello() { println MYCONSTANT }  // won't work
}
```

It's easy to see why it doesn't work expanded out.  An easy work around is to declare your "globals" in a dummy class called e.g. Constants, and then just do a static import on it.  It even works all in a single script.  Example:

```
import static Constants.*

class Constants {
    static final MYCONSTANT = "foobar"
}

println MYCONSTANT

class Helper {
    def hello() { println MYCONSTANT } // works!
}
new Helper().hello()
```

Also, scripts are bit of a special case.  If you declare a variable without `def` or any modifiers such as `final`, (i.e. just use it) it goes into a script-wide binding.  So in this case:

```
CONSTANT = "foobar"
println "foobar"
```

`CONSTANT` is in the script-wide binding, but in:

```
final CONSTANT = "foobar"
println "foobar"
```

`CONSTANT` is a local variable in the script's `run()` method.  More information on this can be found at the archived link to some [Groovy - Scoping and the Semantics of "def"](https://web.archive.org/web/20150108090004/http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scoping+and+the+Semantics+of+%22def%22) page.

Comment: Constants should be enums in the Java 1.5+ world... :)

Comment: @Esko every type of constant should be an Enum? Even something like GRAVITY or PI?   O_o

Comment: @tim_yates: No, an enum should contain all constants which are related to each other. In your example that'd be something like `CelestialObjectAttributes.GRAVITY` or `MathematicConstants.PI`. These can be imported too so that you don't have to repeat the name of the enum and enums are always VM (*or classloader*) global which makes them the perfect alternative for oldschool global constants.

Comment: @Esko I was trying to point out that your initial statement was not true for all constants

Comment: @tim_yates: Why didn't you say so, then? Although, maybe some clarification such as *"Global constants should be expressed as enums..."* would've been nice.

Comment: @ataylor: In your example you have 2 classes, an implicit one 'foo' and an explicit one 'Helper'.  However, what is confusing is that it will not work even if there was no 'Helper' class.  Methods/closures in "foo" can't use the constants declared at the top.

Comment: @justGroovy, you're right, the final modifier changes things a bit unexpectedly in scripts.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: coming from another language I find the scoping issues here a confusing mess... the thing with `final` changing the scope is something I just encountered and rather surprising. the 'Scoping and semantics' link is currently a 404

Comment: This just works: `CONSTANT = "foobar"`

Answer (score 38):

In Groovy 1.8+, you can achieve this using the [`@Field` annotation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html):

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field final String MY_CONSTANT = 'constant'

def printConstant() { println MY_CONSTANT }

printConstant()
```

Comment: @Anentropic: don't miss the import above "import groovy.transform.Field"

Answer (score 2):

The another efficient way to add the global application level constants are
declare one **interface** in suitable package as

```
interface applicationConstants {
//All constants goes here.
    static final float PI = 3.14 
    String ADMIN_USER = "ADMIN"
    Map languages = [
        "en":   "English",
        "hi":   "Hindi",
        "mr":   "Marathi"

    ]
// Like above you can declare all application level code constants here.

}
```

Use of constants in any class as below,

```
 import packageNameContainingInterface.applicationConstants // import statement.
 def adminUser = applicationConstants.ADMIN_USER
 println adminUser
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally wouldn't do it but technically you could do

`Object.metaclass.MYCONSTANT = 'foobar'`

Then every object has it