# Use buildConfigField defined in build.gradle in another place in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have the next chunk of code in my build.gradle:

```
productFlavors {
        //DIMENSION - APP
        slid {
            dimension "app"
            applicationId "com.slid"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0.0"

            manifestPlaceholders = [one_app_id : "273e0-b8f-4c7f-87-0f4eb68da"]
        }
}
```

What I want to do is access `one_app_id` from `manifestPlaceholders` inside my java code.

As I was unable to do so (or at least I was unable to find a way), I want to define a `buildConfigField` `String` with the same value `273e0-b8f-4c7f-87-0f4eb68da` but I'd like to make it a reference to `manifestPlaceholders/one_app_id` so I don't write the ID two times.

My question is: 
`buildConfigField "String", "ONE__ID", '[reference_here]'`
What do I set instead of `[reference_here]` ?

**OR**

How can I do i the other way, i.e. have the ID set as a `buildConfigField` and then set that reference in the `manifestPlaceholder`
For example `manifestPlaceholders = [one_app_id: [?!reference_here?!]]`

**P.S.** don't worry, the ID is not valid :)

Comment: "What do I set instead of [reference_here] ?" -- `FOO` works, if you define `FOO` somewhere, such as in `gradle.properties` or as a simple global variable.

Comment: Yeah, I found the gradle.properties solution, but I'd like the ID value to appear in build.gradle and not somewhere else. I'll use flavors and this project needs to be easily filled out with new data when a new flavor is required (a third party will fill out these values and generate a new build, so it needs to be straight forward, unfortunately :( )

Comment: "but I'd like the ID value to appear in build.gradle" -- then use a global constant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4859715/115145

Comment: It seems I've managed to figure it out. Could you please add your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I would suggest that you write your own answer, so you can show what you used.

Answer (score 0):

Based on CommonsWare's suggestion I've managed to do it like so:

```
ext {
    oneAppId = ""
}

android {

   productFlavors {
            //DIMENSION - APP
            slid {
                dimension "app"
                applicationId "com.slid"
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0.0"

                ext.oneAppId = '"273e0-8567-558da"'
                manifestPlaceholders = [one_app_id : ext.oneAppId] //Used by the third party library
                buildConfigField "String", "ONE_APPID", ext.oneAppId //I'll use this in java
            }
    }

}
```